# Understanding IS NULL OR in a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get my query to show me all cells that have blanks in.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT tblSourceData.[Athlete], tblSourceData.[Gender], tblSourceData.[Competition Date], tblSourceData.[Swim], tblSourceData.[Bike], tblSourceData.[Run]
FROM tblSourceData;
WHERE tblsourcedata.[swim] is null or tblSourceData.[bike] is null or tblSourceData.[run] is null
```

It keeps throwing up an error of 'Characters found after end of SQL statement'

Any idea where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the semi-colon at the end of your `From` clause

Comment: I can not believe thats all it was - Thank you for that. Answer my question so I can mark you as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of your From clause

Answer (score 0):

it's all one statement...only put semi-colon at the END of the SELECT statement